# aggregate functions on groupby object giving incomplete output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        A   B           C           D           ``  category    labels
7937    0   0.00137174  0.0301783   0.00137174      Foo         0
15461   0   0           0.0132548   0.0441826       Bar         1
```

I grouped the frame into a groupby object:

```
groups = df.groupby('category')
```

If I run `groups.count()`, I get complete values:

```
        A      B            C           D               labels
Foo     40     40           40          40              40
Bar     40     40           40          40              40
```

But if I try doing any arithmetic on the group, I get a frame with only the labels back:

```
groups.sum()

Category    Labels
Foo         23
Bar         9
```

I'd like to get the sum/mean/etc for all the other values in the frame.

Let me know if you need me to post more data to help answer. Thanks much.

Comment: that's weird, is it possible to provide the whole dataframe ? or the line where you created it if it's not from a csv file ? thanks

Comment: Its likely that the other columns are not numeric which is why they don't show up in a sum().  Do a `df.dtypes` to verify

Comment: @RayhaneMama it was created through a lot of different functions, originally from CSV data but now highly processed. i can put up a snippet of the dataframe but it's large and messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `agg` (aggregate) and provide a list of functions. The default aggregate functions should be recognized as strings (ie. count, sum, unique...) but you can also define your own

```
groups.agg(['sum', 'count', lambda x : list(x)])
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm also wondering why `lambda x: x.mean()` seems to work while `.agg(['mean'])` gives the same result I had in my original problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you post some data to recreate it then I'll take a look

Comment: Sorry for the meta question but how does one post large chunks of a dataframe in a way that's properly formatted? This looks like a disaster in my pre-published edited version of the post and I'm not sure what how to fix it. (I haven't found an answer on Meta that works, including np.savetext with fixed spaces.

Comment: I wouldn't load the whole dataset. One thing you can do is choose a group that exhibits what you want to show, then filter the original dataframe for that group and use `to_json()`, then upload the json string

Comment: It actually seemed to be an issue with dividing floats by integers, which I thought I'd fixed. But your answer still strangely worked for some functions despite and that was as helpful nonetheless so I'm going to mark it as answered. Thanks.